# JavaScript - function which accepts a string and an index (number) and returns the character at that index

Tags: javascript, function

I want to write a function called `charAt` which accepts a string and an index (number) and returns the character at that index.

The function should return an empty string if the number is greater than the length of the string.

Do not use the built in charAt method - the tests will fail if you do!

```
function charAt(str, num){
  return str.indexOf(num);
}


charAt('awesome', 2);
```

I understand my code is checking to see if the number 2 is contained with the string 'awesome' and is correctly returning -1 which is telling me that the number 2 is not contained in that string.

How do I write code to return what letter starts at index 2?

Comment: `str[num]` works

Comment: Also, typical non-real-life exercise, where you are forbidden to use convenient and existing functions, and instead you are forced to use workarounds. As usual, teacher's imagination is too poor to give their students a real-life problem.

Comment: you can also use `substring`

Answer (score 0):

Basic and simple solution.

```js
function charAt(str, num) {
  return str.slice(num, num + 1) || "";
}
console.log(charAt("awesome", 10));

// OR

const charAt2 = (str, num) => str.slice(num, num + 1) || "";
console.log(charAt2("awesome", 2));

//OR add in prototype
String.prototype.safeCharAt = function safeCharAt(num) {
  return this.slice(num, num + 1) || "";
};
console.log("awesome".safeCharAt(2));
console.log("awesome".safeCharAt(10));
```